# Ubuntu support for HP ZBOOK 15 G6

Tags: networking, hp, ubuntu-drivers

Which Ubuntu version has driver support for HP Zbook 15 G6? Have tried 17.04 but no ethernet and wifi drivers.

Comment: Why are you running such an old version? Please try the latest Ubuntu release (19.10) or the LTS version (18.04).

Comment: 17.04 became EOL in January 2018 and thus no longer supported on this site.

Comment: Didn't work with ubuntu 18.04, have moved to an non LTS latest version which is 19.10 and it's working. Not that anyone cares but I also tried latest Linux Mint  and it didn't work as well.

Comment: I updated the kernel to 5.3.0-40-generic and apparently that got it to work.